# How to run Heroku rails app locally without access to source code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, localhost

My Heroku app is created and it also runs in my big commerce store but I want to run in locally.

Basically, I want to get all file in local machine from Heroku app.

Please help..

Comment: How did you upload your app to Heroku? Do you have access to Heroku's dashboard and git repository?

Comment: Using heroku deploy service and yes i have access heroku app dashboard and git repository.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have access to git repository, you just need to clone it

```
git clone GIT_URL
```

then move into the app root directory

```
cd my_app
```

and then do

```
bundle install
```

now start the server

```
rails server
```

goto `localhost:3000` from your browser..

**Update**

Since you have access to `heroku`, in the app dashboard goto *settings* near the bottom page you will find **Heroku Git URL**, clone that.

In a new empty folder just type this from cmd

```
git clone https://github.com/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-ruby-sinatra.git
```

Comment: Git repository not available

Comment: Check this three image 

When i am trying to clone it show that directory is not empty.

Comment: create a new empty folder and then clone it. Also, I see there's a github page in the images, meaning you have access to source code?

Comment: Yes i want to access source code and want some changes.

But did not get any source code on my empty directory.

Comment: did you run `git clone`?

Comment: https://git.heroku.com/samplesinatra.git

This is my GitHub link generated by Heroku. But in this link no source code available,,

See the image : http://imgur.com/67q02X0

Comment: what do you get when you click on Connected to `Webiarch/samplesinatra` link from the image?

Comment: yes i run .. Let me know one things I run on my CMD or Heroku Consol .

Comment: On the cmd..you use windows? And where does that link take you to?

Comment: http://imgur.com/2CgWpHW ..

Check this image.. First i right code on my windows cmd and now i write on heroku consol.

Comment: Let me explain again I want to get all page and data of heroku app and that is added by himself from click on deploy Heroku button.
Check this link.
http://imgur.com/PcDCH6k

Comment: Ohh man..is that it?? I wonder have you used git/github earlier..anyway....just scroll up on the github page you showed in image above, there's a green button which says *clone or download* that's where you get you git url to clone the repository..check the answer I m updating

Comment: How to manage the heroku environment variables if website is using them?